# Problem with updating data when uploading a new file

Tags: angular, forms, file-upload, error-handling, backend

I'm facing an issue with updating existing data in my application. When I try to update without changing the file field, the code works fine. However, if I try to upload a new file for updating, I encounter a specific error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yviAZ.png)

`

```
saveEdit() {
  const updateData = { ...this.editManualPlansForm.value };

  if (updateData.file) {
    const fileExtension = updateData.file.split('.').pop()?.toLowerCase();
    const allowedFileTypes = ['pdf', 'pptx', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'mp4', 'mp3'];

    if (!allowedFileTypes.includes(fileExtension)) {
      alert('Invalid file type. Please upload a file of type: pdf, pptx, jpg, jpeg, png, gif, mp4, mp3.');
      return; 
    }
  } else {
    delete updateData.file; 
  }

  this.ManualPlanService.updateManualAndPlan(this.cardID, updateData).subscribe(
    (res: any) => {
      console.log('Update successful:', res);
      this.showEditPopup = false;
    },
    (error: any) => {
      console.error('Update failed:', error);
    }
  );
}`
```

Can anyone help me understand and resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance for your assistance.

I attempted to update existing data in my application by uploading a new file. I expected the update process to succeed without any errors, and for the new file to be saved along with the updated data. However, upon uploading the new file and submitting the update form, I encountered an error message stating that the file must be of a specific type (pdf, pptx, jpg, etc.). This was unexpected, as I believed the code was properly configured to accept these file types. Despite verifying that the uploaded file met the required criteria, the error persisted.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I think this: .split('.').pop() might be removing the extension....  you're better off just adding "accept" to the form field.  ex: <input type="file" accept=".pdf, .pptx, etc...">  If they still fudge the input field, your backend will take care of it.